# Require a directive input box text in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a custom directive with an input box. This input is used in many of the pages. I want to require this input field in some of the forms and exclude in others. What should be the best approach to do this?
I am submitting the form from controllers so not sure how this would work in angular?
I am new to angular and not sure how this all will be tie up together.
So essentially this is what I want :

```
<form name="myForm" >
<div ng-contoller="Somecontroller as vm" >
<custom-directive>
this will create an input box like this :
<input type="text"> </input>
</custom-directive>
</div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form I want to ensure that if the text box inside the directive does not have text then I should get an error.

Comment: You should be using ng-required, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, this is your custom directive, with this example you can handle what you want...also you can use directive in all you form but remember do not use with same ngModel, and last one thing always set ngModel in this directive.

```js
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.directive("requiredInput", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                required: "^ngModel",
                template: "<input type='text' ng-model='ngModel' ng-required='true'>",
                scope: {
                    ngModel: "="
                }
            }
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>form 1</h1>

<form name="form">
    <required-input ng-model="form.myInput"></required-input>
    <required-input ng-model="form.myInput2"></required-input>
    {{myInput}}

    <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">submit</button>
</form>
<h1>form 2</h1>
    <form name="form2">
        <required-input ng-model="form2.myInput"></required-input>
        {{myInput2}}

        <button ng-disabled="form2.$invalid">submit</button>
    </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<w-test-directive></w-test-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("wTestDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "<input type='text'/>"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```